# How to create a Calendar or Day Picker in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

I want to create a UI to enable the user to set specific configuration from date1 to date2. To pick the dates I want the calendar to pop up.

To create the calendar, I can put a combo box to choose the month, along with 30 buttons as representative of the days (enabling/disabling some days based on the selected month).

If you know a better way to do this, I would be very thankful if you share it with me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do it like that. You have the full power of Java at your hands. There are many Java libraries for date pickers like this one:

https://toedter.com/jcalendar/

Download the .jar file and add it to your model dependencies. Then you can create the date picker object using the respective API.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/llyoet64h22s39a/AAAgyO3JYFdsR8DGPqsMgEdNa?dl=0) is an AnyLogic example model but it currently only works in AnyLogic 7 (since 8 massively changed how things are displayed). To get it working in AL 8, you might need to ask AL support.

Comment: Sorry for the necrobumping, but I am struggling to add custom widgets to the AnyLogic UI. I noticed that the link of the example is dead. Is it possible to re-upload it?
Thank you!

Comment: Well, it would not work in AL 8 as per the reply. For AL8, you need to find a Java package and use that