# How to add a date picker to AnyLogic model UI?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to add a date picker [like this](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) to my simulation homepage, but I have no idea how to implement it.

*(Note: this is basically a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756678/how-to-create-a-calendar-or-day-picker-in-anylogic), but the answer was written for AL7 and the example is not working anymore)*

Comment: Might be easiest to simply provide a textbox and let users enter dates and times that you then convert into Date objects...

Comment: That is basically what I currently do, but I think having an actual datepicker would be much nicer

Comment: Other way would be to have a website frontend or use the custom UI in the cloud (i.e. a JavaScript wrapper). Creating DatePickers is easy in JavaScript, so just send the chosen dates to the model before it starts as an input...

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to put it into a "pure" AnyLogic model, I hoped there was a relatively easy way to do it. But if there isn't, the textbox will do.

Comment: Not that I am aware of...